# Starting uWSGI server without sudo

Tags: flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy my Flask app using uWSGI, but I can't seem to do it without sudo.

Here is my start script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -v
set -e
cd /var/hpit/hpit_services
/var/hpit/hpit_services/env/bin/uwsgi --http [::]:80 --master --module wsgi --callable app --processes 4 --daemonize ../log/uwsgi.log --pidfile ../server_pid_file.pid
echo server started
```

Here is what I get in the logs:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Mon Jan 26 15:53:26 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 23 January 2015 20:35:44
os: Linux-3.18.1-x86_64-linode50 #1 SMP Tue Jan 6 12:14:10 EST 2015
nodename: <<blocked out>>
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /var/hpit/hpit_services
writing pidfile to ../server_pid_file.pid
detected binary path: /var/hpit/hpit_services/env/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 7962
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 764]
```

Core/socket.c line 764 has this:

```
if (bind(serverfd, (struct sockaddr *) &uws_addr, addr_len) != 0) {
    if (errno == EADDRINUSE) {
        uwsgi_log("probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address (%s).\n", socket_name);
    }
    uwsgi_error("bind()");
    uwsgi_nuclear_blast();
    return -1;
}
```

But I don't have instances of uWSGI running.  This seems to be a permissions issue.  My permissions for /var/hpit, /var/hpit/hpit_services (the location of the app) and /var/hpit/log are bsauer:www-data.  My user us bsauer.

If I append `sudo -E` to the line in my start script that calls the uWSGI binary, it seems to start fine, but I read that a server should not be started as sudo.  I inherited this sysadmin role at work and am a little new to all of this.

Here are my hunches/musings:

- I know that uWSGI can start as one user and drop into another user role, but I don't really understand this process, so perhaps that's the problem.
- uWSGI is trying to access something on the system I'm not aware of

Thanks for your help, I can provide more details if necessary.

**EDIT**

Oddly, my /var/hpit/log/uwsgi.log file is owned by bsauer:bsauer, not bsauer:www-data or www-data:www-data as I would have expected...

**EDIT2**

Ok, from looking at http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example at the bottom of the page, it looks like the problem is running on port 80.  I changed it to 8080, but its still running as bsauer, which I don't think I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with as far as I understand it, if anyone wants to put this is clearer sysadmin language I'll be happy to edit.

The solution had nothing to do with the logs after all.  The problem was that port 80, the default HTTP port, is protected by the system, and only root can bind to that port.  Without sudo, it won't let you bind.  Binding to another port, like port 8080, worked fine.

I wanted to bind to port 80 but still run the server as www-data, so I ended up following the very bottom of this page: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example .  Basically, the socket to port 80 is shared, and uWSGI can access it first as sudo, and then drop down into www-data to run the server.

I still had to use `sudo -E` before calling the uWSGI binary, because it needs root permissions to change uWSGI's user and group ID, but it's ok because the end result is the server then runs in the very restricted www-data user.

In the end, my server start line was:
`sudo -E /var/hpit/hpit_services/env/bin/uwsgi --shared-socket [::]:80 --http =0 --uid 33 --gid 33 --master --module wsgi --callable app --processes 4 --daemonize ../log/uwsgi.log --pidfile ../server_pid_file.pid`